# find command does not find string in subfolders

Tags: find, grep, execute-command

I have a file structure something like this:

```
/apps/base/logs1
and 
/apps/base/logs2
```

Both logs1 and logs2 folders have .log files with some other files as well.

I am trying to do this
From /apps folder I want to be able to find all files (folders and sub-folders) that have the string "ERROR".

This command

```
 find . -name "*.log" -exec grep -H "ERROR" '{}' \; -print
```

Works fine and shows me all .log files directly in the folder when I am in the folder /apps/base/logs1 or /apps/base/logs2.

But when I switch to the folder /apps, this command does not yield any results.

Is there anything that I am missing or need to change? I have tried several other options but I can not get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you run the find command without the -exec, just "find -name '*.log'", does it print out the files you expect to search?

Comment: @Ken yes it does print the file names when I execute just the find . -name "*.log" command.

Comment: What about trying a different command for the sake of troubleshooting? e.g. `find . -name "*.log" -execdir ls -l {} \;` (N.B. you should use `-execdir` not `-exec` for security reasons. See `man find`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got the answer.
Since I was on an enterprise environment, there were many symbolic links created.
I had to explicitly ask find command to also follow the symbolic links. So the command now looks like this:

```
find -L /apps -name "*.log" -exec grep -H "ERROR" '{}' \; -print
```

The problem was directories like logs1 and logs2 were symbolic links, and hence were not followed by the find command. The **-L option** forces the command to look in the sym links as well.